# Redirect loop for Django multi tenanted site when load balancer added

Tags: django, nginx, load-balancing, infinite-loop, http-redirect

I have two virtual hosts each running five sites (multi tenanted). The server has three IP addresses. Two are publicly facing and one is internal.

Both publicly facing web sites have SSL certificates. One site is my staging site, and has a letsencrypt SSL certificate, the other is the live site and has a godaddy SSL certificate.

I first set up a Rackspace load balancer with one node (my cloud instance), copied the certificate and key to the balancer from my server, and used the following nginx configuration successfully to get the load balancer to proxy my site from my web server serving on the internal facing IP

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///run/uwsgi/app/introtest/socket;
}

# configuration of the server, first redirect http to https...
server {
    listen      10.181.104.195:80;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
        return 302 https://$http_host$request_uri;
    }

    # the domain name it will serve for
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /srv/test/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /srv/test/static;
    }


    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        if (-f /srv/maintenance_test.html) {
            return 503;
        } 
        uwsgi_pass  django;

        uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
        uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
        uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
        uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

        uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
        uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
        uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
        uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
        uwsgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
        uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

        uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
        uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
        uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
        uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
        uwsgi_param  X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        uwsgi_param  X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        uwsgi_param  X-Forwarded-Host   $server_name;

    }

    # Error pages
    error_page 503 /maintenance_test.html; 
    location = /maintenance_test.html {
        root /srv;
    }

}
```

As an aside, I don't use permanent redirects if I can help it, and did not with the staging server. The live server was already set up and had permanent redirects to https, but I figure we would always want to redirect the live site to SSL, so the redirects are 301.

After changing the DNS entry for the root domain of my staging sites to the load balancer, this worked fine.

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log
```

showed that requests were coming from the load balancer's internal IP address, and pages were being served correctly.

I changed everything back (that is nginx conf and the DNS entries for the staging root domain), and got staging to serve from the webserver okay. Then I copied the godaddy SSL cert information to the load balancer. Then with the following nginx configuration for the live server:

```
upstream intro_live {
    server unix:///run/uwsgi/app/introsites/socket;
}

server {
    listen <SERVER PUBLIC IP>:80;
    listen <SERVER PUBLIC IP>:443;

    location / {
        return 503;
    }
    error_page 503 /interruption.html; 
    location = /interruption.html {
        root /srv;
    }
}


# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen  10.181.104.195:80;
    # reidrect http to https from load balancer
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
        set $http_test  S${http_host};
    }

    if ($http_test = 'Sintrotravel.com') {
        rewrite ^ https://www.introtravel.com$request_uri;
    }
    if ($http_test = 'Sozintro.com') {
        rewrite ^ https://www.ozintro.com$request_uri permanent;
    }
    if ($http_test = 'Sbalintro.com') {
        rewrite ^ https://www.balintro.com$request_uri permanent;
    }
    if ($http_test = 'Sthaintro.com') {
        rewrite ^ https://www.thaintro.com$request_uri permanent;
    }
    if ($http_test = 'Svietnamintro.com') {
        rewrite ^ https://www.vietnamintro.com$request_uri permanent;
    }

    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /srv/intro/media;
        expires 7d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location /static {
        alias /srv/intro/static;
        expires 1d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }


    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        if (-f /srv/maintenance_on.html) {
            return 503;
        } 
        uwsgi_pass  intro_live;

        uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
        uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
        uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
        uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

        uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
        uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
        uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
        uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
        uwsgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
        uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

        uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
        uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
        uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
        uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
        uwsgi_param  X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        uwsgi_param  X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        uwsgi_param  X-Forwarded-Host   $server_name;

    }

    # Error pages
    error_page 503 /maintenance_on.html; 
    location = /maintenance_on.html {
        root /srv;
    }
}
```

- The first `upstream django` points to my uwsgi config.
- The second server config listens to the server's public facing address, so that if someone's DNS entry for the web site has not been updated, they get a static page saying that the server is in maintenance.
- The third server config listens to port 80 on the internal address, checks if the staging server has set `http_x_forwarded_proto`, and if it has sets a test variable to the domain. I specifically redirect http traffic from the five sites to https.
- The last 503 stuff detects the existence of a file, and if it exists, the site is put into maintenance mode.

There is nothing in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ and my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf looks like this:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 20;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;

        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        # server_tokens off;
        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Once I set the DNS A records for the five sites to point at the load balancer, redirection to https occurs okay, but I get a redirect loop in each of the pages. So, I took out all of the redirects from the config, that is

```
    if ($http_test = 'Sintrotravel.com') {
        rewrite ^ https://www.introtravel.com$request_uri;
    }
    if ($http_test = 'Sozintro.com') {
        rewrite ^ https://www.ozintro.com$request_uri permanent;
    }
    if ($http_test = 'Sbalintro.com') {
        rewrite ^ https://www.balintro.com$request_uri permanent;
    }
    if ($http_test = 'Sthaintro.com') {
        rewrite ^ https://www.thaintro.com$request_uri permanent;
    }
    if ($http_test = 'Svietnamintro.com') {
        rewrite ^ https://www.vietnamintro.com$request_uri permanent;
    }
```

and restarted nginx. I still had a redirect loop. Why??? I understand that the rewrite's are permanent, but this not because of the difference in `return 302` and `rewrite`, becuase the server is still on an infinite redirect loop when I take out *all* redirects. I can't spend a lot of time experimenting with the live site for obvious reasons. Really I need to cut across in 10-15 minutes Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking about it, I realised it had to be the Django application that was the issue. Nothing to do with nginx. There was a setting

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
```

that made django redirect http traffic to https (this was false in staging). This becomes an issue when you add the load balancer, as the load balancer receives https traffic, but it only delivers not secure traffic on port 80 to my web server/application. This is why you have redirect on the condition

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {...
```

(which is set by the load balancer) in your nginx configuration. Removing the redirect in this way just from nginx would not fix the problem, I had to remove it completely from django.

No matter how experienced you are DNS is confusing if you are in a hurry because of its distributed nature, and when a site that earns money is down, you are in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

Django can address that via this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER

Adding:
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

And making sure your proxy sets the appropriate header will prevent the redirect loop.  What happens is that your proxy doesn't tell Django that the connection is secure, so it keeps redirecting to the secure version although it is already secure - hence the infinite loop.  Providing the header is one of the ways to address this.